# Find real and imaginary part of $w=z^{3i}$ function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find real and imaginary part of $w=z^{3i}$ function.
When I try to do something with that, I stuck with $(x+iy)^{3i}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show your work and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on providing context in your question to better assist the community.

Comment: Try $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @Laufen, formatted. I am rewrite z as $x+iy$ and stuck with what to do with $(x+iy)^{3i}$

Comment: @MostafaAyaz then I get $(re^{i\theta})^{3i}=r^{3i}*e^{-3\theta}=$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$w=z^{3i}$$
$$\implies \ln w=3i\ln z=3i[\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+i\tan^{-1}(y/x)]$$
$$\implies \ln w=\frac{3}{2}i\ln(x^2+y^2)-3\tan^{-1}(y/x)]$$
$$\implies w=\exp[i\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}] \exp[-3\tan^{-1}(y/x)]$$
$$\Re(w)=\exp[-3\tan^{-1}(y/x)] \cos\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2},$$ $$\Im(w)=\exp[-3\tan^{-1}(y/x)] \sin\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: @Z_Ahmed, why there are 2i ln z and not 3i lnz ?

Comment: Thanks I have corrected it now.

Comment: how did you converted ln z into [] thng? Can you explain it?

Comment: $\ln(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+y^2)+i\tan^{-1} (y/x)$ is the definition of $]ln z$.

Comment: @Z_Ahmed shouldn't we in $\implies w=\exp[i\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}] \exp[-3\tan^{-1}(y/x)]$ line write root of 2nd power, but to take $(x^2 + y^2)$ to the third power? If I remember correctly, something what is taken to the power m/n is a n-th power root with an expression inside in m-th power.

Comment: And please, explain how did you move root from exp. And how (and why) you've wrote such R(w) and I(w) so?

Comment: Note that $e^{it}=\cos t+ i\sin t$, $\Re (e^{it})= \cos t$, $\Im (e^{it})=\sin t$